# Походження фразеологізму "Байдики бити", синоніми до виразу

Tags: етимологія, синоніми, фразеологізми

Мене зацікавив фразеологізм «байдики бити» в реченні: Та коли воно таке було, щоб ото прості люди та своїх дітей **байдики бити** привчали (Збанацький, Морська чайка).

В "Словнику найуживаніших фразеологізмів" подається тлумачення стійкого сполучення "байдики бити": бути без діла, **ледарювати, розважатися**. Останні два дієслова виступають простими синонімами до виразу. 
Щоб дізнатися походження ідіоми я звернулася до Вікісловника.

У ньому подано більш конкретне значення стійкого словосполучення і додаткові прості синоніми: нічого не робити, нічим не займатися; **байдикувати**.Також є приклад синоніма-фразеологізма: **посиденьки справляти**. Але про походження не йдеться.
Із статті [«Бити байдики значення фразеологізму»](http://sz-t.ru/biti-bajdiki-znachennja-frazeologizmu/)з'ясувала дві версії походження ідіоми:

> Найпопулярніша на сьогоднішній день версія, полягає в тому, що в ранні часи при виготовленні виробів з дерева, необхідно було підготувати ці самі заготовки (**байдики**).
> Друга версія полягає в тому, що існувала гра, сенс якої полягав у вибиванні дерев'яною палицею побудованих з байдики фігур (будиночків, гармат та ін.). В даний час ця гра називається містечками.

Цікаво, чи існують ще версії походження фразеологізму. Я знаю ще один складений синонім до нього - **валяти дурня**. Чи є ще інші синоніми-фразеологізми?

Answer (score 2):

[Бити байдики](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8#%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F) - нічого не робити, нічим не займатися.

[**Походження**](http://pan-ta-pani.com/20907-pohodzhennya-viraziv.html):

> Що таке "байдики", хто і коли їх "б'є"? З давніх пір кустарі робили
>   ложки, чашки і інший посуд з дерева. Щоб вирізати ложку, треба було
>   відколоти від колоди цурку - байдики. Заготовляти байдики доручалося
>   підмайстрам: це було легке, дріб'язкова справа, що не вимагає
>   особливого уміння.

Інформацію про те, що "байдик" - це "брус чи колода" можна знайти і в [ЕСУМі](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page=115).

Знайшов ще [тут](http://ukr-article.com/index.php?newsid=32811) дві версії (зазначу, що це невмілий переклад чи рерайт [російської статті](http://fb.ru/article/132270/chto-znachit-bit-baklushi-znachenie-i-proishojdenie-vyirajeniya-bit-baklushi) (тому я дещо повиправляв), тому не варто 100% довіряти поданій інформації):

> Менш поширена, але найбільш правдоподібна - це версія про нічних
>   сторожів. Вони в старовину обходили територію, що охоронялася і
>   стукали в калатала, дерев'яні чурки, які й називалися байдики. Заняття
>   це було нескладне, не вимагало особливої кваліфікації та вмінь,
>   потрібно було просто бути присутнім на роботі. Тому, коли людина
>   нічого не робить, сидячи на роботі, ледарює, вважається, що він б'є
>   байдики.
>
> Ще одна не менш цікава версія - це походження фразеологізму від назви
>   будь-якого дрібної водойми на Поволжі. Потрапивши в такі озерця під
>   час повені, риба взимку починає задихатися від нестачі кисню. І якщо
>   розбити лід, то часто вона вистрибує сама. У великі морози без
>   особливих зусиль можна наловити багато риби. Процес такої риболовлі
>   місцеві називають "бити байдики".

[Синоніми](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=24&t=260):

> нічого не робити, байди бити; баглаї били (годувати, гнути); гандри
>   бити, діал.; бомки бити, заст.; ханьки м’яти; собак ганяти; дурня
>   валяти (клеїти); гав (ґави) ловити; горобцям дулі давати; лежати
>   лежнем; (сидіти без діла) сидні (посиденьки) справляти; сидіти склавши
>   (згорнувши) руки; (постійно гуляти, уникати праці) походеньки
>   справляти; і (й, ні, ані) за холодну воду ; і пальцем не торкатися (не
>   приторкатися) до чого; з-під пазурчика (пазурця) собі не виколупнути;
>   сім неділь (вихідних) на тиждень справляти (мати).

Comment: Так, це переклад російської статті [«Что значит „бить баклуши“? Значение и происхождение выражения „бить баклуши“»](http://fb.ru/article/132270/chto-znachit-bit-baklushi-znachenie-i-proishojdenie-vyirajeniya-bit-baklushi). Чи стосується написане про _баклуши_ також _байдиків_ — я не знаю (можливо, ці слова мають щось спільне в походженні, можливо, ні).

Comment: Пропонуєте забрати ті дві версії із відповіді?

Comment: Я б частково залишив через 2 причини: (1) бачу, той сайт багатьох ошукав, тож краще явно згадати його й пояснити, чому та стаття недостовірна, ніж просто вилучати інформацію; (2) випадково так склалося, що частина інформації, можливо, є достовірною — [ЕСУМ](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page=115) теж каже, що _байда_ — дерев'яний інструмент і човен (і можливо, колись означало «брус, колода»), тому ту частину, що підтримується ЕСУМом, можна залишити з поясненням, мовляв, здається, вона підтримується ЕСУМом.

Comment: Тобто залишив би, але з суттєвою переробкою, мовляв, такий-то сайт пропонує такі-то версії, але вони недостовірні тому що…, але при цьому така-то частина інформації, здається, підтримується ЕСУМом, тому можливо, частина є достовірною.

Comment: Вніс деякі зміни

Comment: До речі, перепрошую, я спочатку не зрозумів, що перша версія зацитована з іншого джерела (я чомусь подумав, що вона звідти ж). Але те джерело **теж** виявилося перекладом [російської статті](http://www.aif.ru/archive/1727312), хоч й іншої. Отож фактично це про слово _баклуши_ (хоч може статися так, що _байдики_ й _баклуши_ мають подібне походження).

Answer (score 0):

На сайті ["Статті українською мовою"](http://ukr-article.com/index.php?newsid=32811) написані декілька варіантів походження вислову **"байдики бити"**

> Найпоширеніша версія походження виразу
>
> Але найчастіше можна зустріти інше пояснення значення даного поєднання
>   слів. Більшість вчених схиляються до думки, що оборот "бити байдики"
>   раніше означав виготовлення заготовки для дерев'яних ложок і іншого
>   посуду. Дерево було основним матеріалом для домашнього начиння, тому і
>   процес биття байдиків був дуже поширений. Це неважка заняття, яке не
>   потребує особливих знань і умінь. З такою справою легко справлявся
>   навіть десятирічна дитина. Часто над такими труднощами посміювалися,
>   тому в сучасну мову вираз перейшло в такому значенні.

Як зазначено в коментарі - ця стаття виявилася перекладом російської статті "Что значит "бить баклуши"? Значение и происхождение выражения "бить баклуши", але на мою думку має право на існування в даній відповіді.

Також є схожа версія походження даного фразеологізму на цьому [сайті](http://pan-ta-pani.com/20907-pohodzhennya-viraziv.html)

> Бити байдики  Що таке "байдики", хто і коли їх "б'є"? З давніх пір
>   кустарі робили ложки, чашки і інший посуд з дерева. Щоб вирізати
>   ложку, треба було відколоти від колоди цурку - байдики. Заготовляти
>   байдики доручалося підмайстрам: це було легке, дріб'язкова справа, що
>   не вимагає особливого уміння.

***"Бити байдики"*** [синоніми](http://dovidka.biz.ua/biti-baydiki-znachennya-frazeologizmu/)

> - посиденьки справляти, байдикувати;
> - гав (ґави) ловити;
> - горобцям дулі давати;
> - лежати лежнем;
> - і за холодну воду не браться;
> - горобців лічити;
> - у стелю плювати;
> - лежні справляти.

Comment: Ця стаття виявилася перекладом російської статті [«Что значит „бить баклуши“? Значение и происхождение выражения „бить баклуши“»](http://fb.ru/article/132270/chto-znachit-bit-baklushi-znachenie-i-proishojdenie-vyirajeniya-bit-baklushi). Тому не дивно, що вона починається зі слів «з плином часу багато слова і вирази **в російській мові**» й містить багато граматичних помилок («багато слова», «тому і вираз це було всім зрозуміло», «лодирнічать», «всім був знайомий процес виготовлення байдики», «чи було в давнину вираз»).

Comment: Просто ця стаття стосується _байдиків_ лиш у тій мірі, в якій _байдики_ й рос. _баклуши_ мають спільне походження. Якщо припускати, що ці слова споріднені, то ми можемо припускати, що написане в оригіналі про рос. _баклуши_ стосується й _байдиків_. А спільне таки може щось виявитися, бо, мені здається, [ЕСУМ](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page=115) дає в чомусь схожу трактовку — але може й не виявитися.